# Understanding UIImage size property compare to UIView frame size Property

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiimage

I'm trying to scale down UIImage to fit the exact same size my UIView has, Tho i'm not sure what is the exact relations between them.
This is the way i'm checking if my UIImage bigger than my UIView.

```
let rect = preview.frame
if croppedImage.size.width  * croppedImage.scale > rect.size.width * UIScreen.
{
//RESIZE
}
```

**Is this the correct way? Does the values speaking at the same dimensions?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `UIImage` [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImage/scale), referring to the `scale` property:

> If you multiply the logical size of the image (stored in the `size`
>   property) by the value in this property, you get the dimensions of the
>   image in pixels.

From the `UIWindow` [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/scale), referring to its own `scale` property:

> This value reflects the scale factor needed to convert from the
>   default logical coordinate space into the device coordinate space of
>   this screen. The default logical coordinate space is measured using
>   points. For standard-resolution displays, the scale factor is 1.0 and
>   one point equals one pixel. For Retina displays, the scale factor is
>   2.0 and one point is represented by four pixels.

So you should be able to compare `croppedImage.size.width * croppedImage.scale` with `rect.size.width * UIScreen.scale`. However, you may want to consider placing your `UIImage` into a `UIImageView`. Then you can set the `frame` property on the `UIImageView` to your view's frame and voila! (Note, however, that this may stretch your image.)

Comment: Hey Evan, thanks for answering! I'm adjusting the UIIMageViw size to the same aspect as the image, so it's fine :) Bottom line, what i have done, is correct? Thanks! :)